# MissingMethodException in application on Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have the following exception in my application when it's downloaded from marketplace (as beta):

> MissingMethodException: Could not load type [and here my regular application class name goes].

The weird thing is that happens ONLY after app was downloaded from Markerplace. When I run application from locally build XAP, everything goes fine.
The exception occurs only on Windows Phone 7 phones, for Windows Phone 8 everything is OK.
Even more strange is that this error happens even when I revert to revisions that were working for sure! I suggest that something has changed in XAP repacking scheme in Marketplace that has broken this, but have no ideas how to overcome the problem.
Has anyone any ideas on what to do, except removing code on random, publishing and seeing whether it works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide anymore information about where the exception occurs in your app? does the stack trace indicate the line number?

Answer (score 0):

It's really weird, but the problem disappeared by itself. I was submitting different revisions of my code to marketplace (from early near-empty versions) to track down what change had caused the issue, but when next portion of publications was ready I found out that the problem has gone!

I noticed that on Friday (Dec 13) it look unusually long for publications to appear in the Marketplace - usually it takes 2-3 hours, but my publications submitted in the morning appeared only next day. And, these publications were functioning without this strange error.

So I'm even more convinced of my suggestion about changing XAP processing.
Hope they fixed it and this never happens again.
@Neil, thanks for trying to help!